# building android_apps errors on Android Studio

Tags: ros, android-core, rosjava-core, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I tried use Android Studio to import the latest android_apps, but I got build errors.

```
$ git clone -b indigo https://github.com/rosjava/android_apps.git
```

And I got following build errors:

```
Error:(161, 16) error: cannot find symbol method addLayer(ViewControlLayer)
Error:(162, 16) error: cannot find symbol method addLayer(OccupancyGridLayer)
Error:(163, 16) error: cannot find symbol method addLayer(LaserScanLayer)
Error:(164, 16) error: cannot find symbol method addLayer(PathLayer)
Error:(165, 16) error: cannot find symbol method addLayer(MapPosePublisherLayer)
Error:(166, 16) error: cannot find symbol method addLayer(InitialPoseSubscriberLayer)
```

It looks like the VisualizationView class in maven central repo did NOT have addLayer method.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220324/building-android_apps-errors-on-android-studio/) by [kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/22505/kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2015-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think maybe the APi got changed. I saw a commit which removes the addLayer method in VisualizationView class. But the official android_apps  still call it.

https://github.com/rosjava/android_core/commit/f4f4c5b56f5d1e86ab1bfd7e44cc8c7493dec689

---

Originally posted by [kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/22505/kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com/) with karma: 159 on 2015-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/22505/kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com/) on 2015-11-12**:
change the above code to this ..

mapView.onCreate(Lists.newArrayList(
viewControlLayer,
occupancyGridLayer,
laserScanLayer,
pathLayer,
mapPosePublisherLayer,
initialPoseSubscriberLayer
));